# Creating a custom EditText with text view in bordered linear layout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, custom-controls

I need to design custom edittext which looks like this here in the image. I want to design something like this.

[image: My Desired output]

Comment: what you have tried so far ??

Comment: @Fantomas.., I didn't started anything yet I just included only drawables

Comment: If you have not started... start and try first, here you are welcome to post issue and discuss problem, not to get your job done without doing anything

Comment: @Mohit... Actually I'm beginner in android now.., and I'm not experienced in this type of design., nd that's why I asked without trying.., Now from this solution by nilesh., I got some basic ideas., So now I'll try something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Name" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Name" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Name" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Name" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make like this

CardView (With Corner radius)

```
Linearlayout (Verticle)

    LinearLayout (Horizontal)
        TextView,Editext

    View (For line)

    LinearLayout (Horizontal)
        TextView,Editext

    View (For line)     

    LinearLayout (Horizontal)
        TextView,Editext
```